# How to Render Html Source code in Jquery and display in Dialog Popup

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a form that allow users to enter custom html source code into it.

Right now what I want to achieve is to provide a preview button so that after users fill in their custom html and click on preview button, a JQuery Dialog pop up will appear showing them how their html will look like.

It is kind of like a wysiwyg, only difference is that when the preview is pop up, users are not allow to edit on the pop up. It is just to give them the look and feel of what they have coded.

In my JQuery it is as below.

```
function preview_enhanced(event)
        {
            var b = $("#enhanced_listing_modal").val();
            var content = $.parseHTML(b);

            $("#enhanced_listing_modal").html(content).dialog({
                width: 900,
                height: 600,
                modal: true, 
                buttons: {
                    "Close Preview": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

I am able to get the html string that is input by users which is

```
$("#enhanced_listing_modal").val();
```

However sadly, I am not able to successfully render the html and display on the Dialog pop up successfully. Based on the above code, it give me the html source on the pop up.

I have also tried changing

```
$("#enhanced_listing_modal").html(content).dialog({ 
to
$("#enhanced_listing_modal").dialog({
```

The result is the same with the html source in the pop up.

My Html code I am testing is a simple one

```
<html>
  <header><title>This is title</title></header>
  <body>
     Hello world
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to render the html in dialog pop up? Or where I stupidly done wrong. Thanks

Comment: don't create the dialog on the input element create a new div on which you will call the dialog function.

Comment: Thank I think You got it right. It works. Cheers